# Event type and SDL_QUIT are incompatible

Tags: c++, sdl2

I'm following the Lazy Foo SDL2 tutorials, and I've run into a problem when trying to poll for events. While I'm polling for the events, the event type and `SDL_QUIT` throw an error saying the operand types are incompatible when trying to see if they're equal.

```
SDL_Event e;

while (!quit)
{
    // Handle vents on queue
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) > 0)
    {
        // User requests quit
        if (e.type == SDL_Quit)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I double-checked and everything is linked correctly, and I've tried other scenarios and it always says the same thing. Does anyone have any ideas about what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SDL_Quit with lowercase letters u, i, and t is a function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Quit), not an enumeration constant or type.

[It looks like you want SDL_QUIT with all uppercase letters](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType#SDL_QUIT), as [shown in the documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_QuitEvent).

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot.

Comment: Note that I've never worked with SDL - this was just 30 seconds of typing "SDL_Quit" into a search engine. So, get into the habit of doing that first, and you can reduce your problem-solving cycle from 4 hours to under a minute. 